# Variable declaration outside of case in switch - to DRY code

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Lets take this example:

```
let name;

switch (name) {

  case "John":
    personsName = "little John";
  break;

  case "Bob":
    personsName = "Bob almighty";
  break;

}
```

Can I take `personName =` out of each case, put it in on top somehow and leave allocation only?

So it would like:

```
case "Bob":
  "Bob almighty";
break;
```

Otherwise with 50 cases I would have to repeat `personName =` text 50 times. If it is not possible, why?

Comment: Just don't use a `switch` statement at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Create a map** of `name` vs `personName`

```
var map = {
  "John" :  "little John",
  "Bob" : "Bob almighty"
}
```

Now get your personName as

```
var personName = map[name];
```

No need to use `switch case`.

Comment: Thanks. What if instead of strings I would have had objects? Such as `case "Bob": personName = bobObject; break;`

Comment: value in a map can be an `object` as well, but the actual solution may depend on your use case. `map` is good enough if just retrieval based on name is required.

Comment: +1, you got the point. But for completion's sake, since he asked why he can't do that, i would say the following.
@lovemyjob The fact that you can't simply write a `"string"` into a switch case is cause you're simply getting it to generate a syntax error, since you do nothing and the simple string means nothing to js. The best you can do, is writing a function that takes the name as a param and in which `each switch` case returns the string(which will be the return value of the function then). Then just use the function to valorize the variable, but I still recommend the @gurvinder372's way.

Comment: Thanks guys. Thanks @riot for explanation. Am I correct thinking that this example with object would work? `var map = { "Bob" : bobObject }; var personName = map.bobObject;` ?

Comment: This won't work, since if you want to get the value inside a map you must target it through the key, so the right approach would be `var personName = map.Bob`

Comment: @lovemyjob riot is correct, you need to apply key to the map to get value, not the other way round.